# Return List String of amx to aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

i have a web service asmx which return a *List<string>, i'm trying to call the web service from the homepage.aspx , but i can't figured out on how to return it as list<string> or datatable*

my asmx , i'm calling a stored procedure

```
        public List<string> GetOrders(String idsuscriber)
```

my aspx :  ( i know it's lame)

```
    public void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.TestSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.TestSoapClient();
               
            // input the id
            string Number = NumberTextBox.Text; 
            var ListeOrder = client.GetOrders(NumberTextBox.Text).Data;
            foreach (var item in ListeOrder)
            {
                ResultCarte.Text += item.Order;
             
            }
       }
```

the output page is like this

Order1Order2Order3

i know i'm missing something that's for sure.

Comment: Why would you call a web service from the same site with code behind? You call + use that web service from client side code. If you wanting to use server side code, then just call the SAME routines and code that the web service is calling then, right?

Comment: Yes i'm using a server side fot the web service, i can't use to same routine because in the web service i'm using stored procedure with oracle

Comment: And why not? Create a static method that hits and pulls the data, and have both your code and the web service page/code call that ONE and same routine. After all the web service code is already going to be a static method. So, I fail to see why both the web service/asmx page, and your code behind on the web page can't call the same routine that returns the same data. Only difference is the web method going to return some xml, or these days json data. But I fail to see why these two routines can'lt call/use/consume one same method that hits the oracle database.

Comment: Suggesting that you move out of the web method the code that pulls the data from oracle. (Even place that code in the asmx page as a non web method). Thus both behind (anyplace in your code behind), and also the web method can consume that same code to return the data. Only difference is the web method as noted return json or xml.  At the end of the day, you still only have "one" developer cost to write that oracle data pull code, and only one instance of that code will exist. So we not actually calling the web method from code behind anymore.